# Ubuntu on VirtualBox character outputs differently

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, character-encoding

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Server on Virtual Box + Mac.

When I type [, ], \, {, }, | etc I get the following outputs.

[image]

I have UTF on locale.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I found that I can type | by right option+shift+| on Mac. But how can I set it so that I can type normally without holding right+option key?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your locales, it is in your key mappings. The kernel maintains a mapping of keyboard scan codes (the key index values a keyboard outputs) to symbols, which appears to be incorrect. Most likely, Linux thinks that it receives scan codes from a PC keyboard, while in fact it receives Mac-flavoured scan codes.

To choose a key map, reconfigure the `keyboard-configuration` package:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Here you can select the correct keyboard layout.